# VisualStudio2008でiniファイルを読み込んでOracleに接続する方法

Tags: c++, visual-studio, oracle

はじめまして、タイトルの通りですが
iniファイルの情報を読み込んでDB接続し、接続をDeleteする機能を作ろうとしております。

Comment: その前にVisual Studio 2008は既に延長サポートも終了して5年近く経とうとしています [Visual Studio 2008](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/lifecycle/products/visual-studio-2008) が、使って大丈夫ですか？最新のものに変えた方が良いのでは？ そして質問に記述された内容では回答するために必要な情報が不足していて簡潔で的確な助言や回答が付きにくいでしょう。例えばMFC/ATL/Win32直接など、どういった形のアプリケーションでしょう？ こちらのヘルプ記事を参考にもっと具体的な情報を加えて回答しやすいようにしてください。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: 質問/タイトルの最初の部分については、こちらの記事とかが関連するでしょう。Win32APIなら[iniファイルを操作するためのAPI(メモ)](https://www.inasoft.org/webhelp/rnsf7/HLP000228.html)に列挙されているAPI, MFCなら[CWinApp クラス](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/cpp/mfc/reference/cwinapp-class?view=msvc-170) の`GetProfileBinary/GetProfileInt/GetProfileString`など。

Comment: いろいろ調べた、と書いてありますが、どういうキーワードで何を調べたんですか？"oracle c++"で検索してもNugetとかいきなり出てこないと思うけれど。

Comment: 「ODBCを使用しても接続ができるようですが、いまいち理解が出来ません。」は感想であって質問文ではないですよね？ 何を求めているのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

いまいち何を求めているのかわかりませんが…質問文に答えるなら。

[ODBC; Microsoft Open Database Connectivity](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/sql/odbc/microsoft-open-database-connectivity-odbc?view=sql-server-ver16)というAPIを使うことになるでしょうか。ODBCはインターフェースとドライバが分離されています。

- インターフェース部分
  かなり昔にOSに標準搭載されるようになっており、いつでも呼び出し可能。
- ドライバ部分

  - [ODBC Driver for Oracle](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/sql/odbc/microsoft/odbc-driver-for-oracle?view=sql-server-ver16)
    かなり昔にOSに標準搭載された経緯により、32bit版だけ残っている。64bit版は未提供。また、希望するOracleバージョンに接続可能かはよくわからない（Oracle8が限定的という記述あり）。
  - [Instant Client ODBCソフトウェア](https://www.oracle.com/jp/database/technologies/releasenote-odbc-ic.html)
    Oracle社によって配布されているドライバ。

Microsoftによる [C/C++ ODBCサンプルアプリケーション](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/sql/connect/odbc/cpp-code-example-app-connect-access-sql-db?view=sql-server-ver16)があります。コードそのものはSQL Serverへ接続するものですが、上記の通り操作しているインターフェース部分は共通なので接続先を適切に選べば参考にはなるでしょう。ただし、プロジェクトファイルは .vcxproj と Visual Studio 2010以降の形式になっているため、 .cpp / .h を参考にするぐらいかも。

---

まぁ、Oracleに限定するなら[Oracle C and C++ Interfaces](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/oci.html)として他にも接続方法が提供されています。